# Ruby Unicode Encoding

Tags: ruby, unicode

What is the Unicode encoding for Ruby? I know that most languages are encoded in UTF-16 like Java. I was wondering what Ruby was encoded in. I've checked the documentation, but can't find any reference to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of encodings supported in Ruby. Try typing the following in irb:

```
Encoding.name_list
```

Also see these blog entries:

[Ruby 1.9 String](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string)

[Ruby 1.9: default encodings](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings)

Comment: (You didn't specify version, so i assumed 1.9.)

Comment: Do you know what the default encoding is?

Comment: @VictorKmita : it depends. The blog entry i linked above (Ruby 1.9: default encodings) is the most clear explanation that i've seen.